# Using If function but only want workdays

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula that is allowing me to see days from start date.
Once I enter in the final date it stops counting using this formula which is perfect, but is adding weekends.
I only want workdays:

```
=(IF($I6:I="",TODAY()-$F6:F,$I6:I-$F6:F))
```

[image]

I added network days at the beginning of the formula but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting networkdays at the beginning like you did, try formatting it like this instead.

```
=IF($I6="",NETWORKDAYS($F6,TODAY()),NETWORKDAYS($F6,$I6))
```